# Jmeter 5.4.3 with mysql-connector-java-8.0.30 -> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to connect Jmeter to MySql but getting error

Here is my config:

- Windows 2019
- Java 11
- MySql version 8.0.30-commersial
- mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar placed as required in jmeter lib folder
- Jmeter 5.4.3

When trying to start jmeter plan an Error appear -> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

What driver should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know "what driver should you use", given you

1. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
2. Properly set up [driver class name](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-driver-name.html)
3. [JDBC URL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html)
4. And the [validation query](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/setting-up-lightweight-validationquery-for-mysql-744527619.html)

you should be good to go with your setup.

I can tell for sure that JMeter version you're using is kind of [violating JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version), you should upgrade to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever is the latest JMeter version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: Jmeter 5.5 - same result
Tried driver name com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver - same result
I verified that mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar is picked up by jmeter while loading the test plan(using sysinternals)
Any more ideas?